# Why does the "then" keyword exist in Lua when "do" could have been reused?

Tags: lua

Why do both keywords "then" and "do" exist?

```
if x == 1 do
    print(x)
end
```

is just as readable as

```
if x == 1 then
    print(x)
end
```

Comment: This is not really a programming question.

Comment: I think there might be some deep understanding about a part of lua's grammar that can be reached by understanding why this is the case.

Comment: They may not have even considered it, or it might be ambiguous. But you would have to ask the designers.

Comment: Also consider that `do ... end` is a valid construct, similar to `{ statements }` in C.

Comment: Nice idea to simplify the language.

Comment: @EJP One of them (@lhf) commented on this thread :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The authors say "we explicitly designed Lua to have a simple, familiar syntax", and the "if-then" combination is generally well-known from many other often-used programming languages (taking into account that Lua was designed something like 20 years ago, think Basic or Pascal).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good idea, but IMHO it isn't because of alternative choices.

I mean, what would this code become?

```
if a == 1 then
  do_stuff()
else
  do_something_else()
end
```

To be coherent you would probably need something like this, which I do not think is better than the status quo:

```
if a == 1 do
  do_stuff()
else do
  do_something_else()
end
```

Comment: It may look like `if a==1 do smth1() don't smth2() end`  :-)

Answer (score 0):

from a mathematical point of view(as programming is based of maths) "if" takes the form "if a is true then b is true else c is true". in terms of while the mathematical version cannot be easily ported to programming so it was reworked to suit the environment thus the more programming appropriate "do".